# MongoDB: E11000 duplicate key error index, React Native axios request

Tags: mongodb, reactjs, mongoose, react-native, redux-thunk

So I am getting a weird error when trying to make a POST request to an locally served api that I am running. I can most POST requests all day in Postman and everything works fine. The second I try and make a POST request from my react-native app everything goes to shit.

Here is the error I receive on the server side:
[image: I receive a 500 error]

Here are some pictures of the server side request handling:

The function that is immediately ran after a post request is sent to `http://localhost:3030/api/v1/users/register`
[image]

The function that is ran pre-save for password encryption and such:
[image]

And finally the function sending the POST request in my react-native app:
[image]

I don't really understand what is happening here so if anyone can offer any help it would be much appreiated! Thanks.

Comment: Also, please post code and error messages as plain text in the future, it's much easier to work with for people answering your question.

Comment: Hi Charles - as well as changing your screenshots into actual text in your question, can you also confirm that you've double-checked that the POST request from react-native app is just the same as the POST requests from Postman - all the same headers etc ?

Comment: It turns out there was weird typo in my backend that was causing it. Sorry about the hassle